# Creating A Checkbox System with Show/Hide of Entries - How To?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, all I am trying to do is create classes for a series of table fields.

Each class could apply to each table field more than once.

In the Javascript, I wanted to create a script, relating to a series of checkboxes. When each checkbox is checked or unchecked the classes related would disappear.

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="check" value="Number1" checked> Contents <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="check" value="Number2" checked> Contents <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" name="check" value="Number3" checked> Contents <br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" name="check" value="Number4" checked> Contents <br>
```

Then any table field with a specific class should disappear via this Javascript:

```
function topicSorter() {
    $("#Checkbox1").onclick = function () {if ($("#Checkbox1").checked) {$('.class1').show(); } else {$('.class1').hide(); }
        };
    $('.class1').show();   
}
```

I can only seem to get this to work without using jQuery and only using classes via `getElementById`, but not using any variation of 'class' like `getElementByClassName`...

Its not working.

Sorry for clogging up this internet with all of this nonsense.

Comment: It's JavaScript, not Java

Comment: I don't see any classes in your markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value's in each checkbox to be the numbers 1-4. Then try the following code:

```
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
        var value = $(this).attr("value");

        $('.class' + value).toggle(this.checked);
    });
```

This code will now fire each time a checkbox is clicked, find the corresponding value, and hide or show the related class.

Comment: You could shorten the core of this to `$('.class' + value).toggle(this.checked);`

Comment: Thanks for the edit, was unaware I could accomplish everything with that one line :).

Comment: Could do `$('.class' + $(this).val()).toggle(this.checked);`

Answer (score 1):

```
<input name="filter" type="checkbox" value="class-1" /> Class 1
<input name="filter" type="checkbox" value="class-2" /> Class 2
<input name="filter" type="checkbox" value="class-3" /> Class 3
<input name="filter" type="checkbox" value="class-4" /> Class 4
```

---

```
function SetFilter()
{
    var checked = new Array();
    $("input[type='checkbox'][name='filter']:checked").each(function(){
        checked.push("." + $(this).val());
    });    

    var value = checked.join(",");    
    $("tr").filter(":not(" + value + ")").hide();
    $("tr").filter(value).show();
}

$("input[type='checkbox'][name='filter']").change(SetFilter);

SetFilter();
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/NxcPL/

Comment: Thanks for this as well by the way. I apologize for my vernacular, I am still trying to figure Javascript out.